# Using a progress bar or wait indicator during webservice call

Tags: c#, web-services

I am using [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute an "Import" web-service call;

This import operation call can take about 5 seconds to complete, so i was wondering how i could best visually entertain the user. I have seen that most progress bars are more or less used in loop operations where they get updated per object processed. In my doWorker, i just have the webservice call;

Something like :

```
Details importinfo = (Details)sender;
e.Result = WebService.ImportMe(importinfo);
```

So will it be smart to have a progress bar in such an operation or some animation while the user waits for completion ? How can i best approach this ?

Comment: You can consider an progress bar set to `Indeterminate`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rcvhm.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have no idea how long it will take and/or at what "point" of the operation you are you can set the `Style` to [`ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[image]